# How do I get the shine back on the bottom of my acrylic shower stall?

Tags: shower, acrylic

How do I get the shine back on the bottom of my acrylic shower stall?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably mineral deposits from your water.
Clean it with vinegar, or CLR.  Then, get a squeegee and wipe down the shower after you use it to keep it clean for longer.